# finding memory leaks in c code on linux environment

Tags: c, valgrind

hello i got a problem using valgrind 
when i use it with  `valgrind --leak-check=full` and afterwards the name of excution file it tells me in which blocks the memory leak is but when i cant find to which pointer i did use free.
is there some sort of flag that tells the name of the pointer.
if there is anyway to tell me where the leak is on visual studio i would very much like to hear about it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't tell you the name of the pointer, because the whole idea of a memory leak is that *no* pointer points at the memory any more (at least, for the kinds of leaks that Valgrind describes as *"definitely lost"*).

What it *can* tell you is the source file and line number where the memory was allocated - you then will need to look up that line in your source to figure out where the memory is *supposed* to be deallocated.  For example, if the Valgrind loss record looks like:

```
==17110== 49 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 17 of 35
==17110==    at 0x4023D6E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
==17110==    by 0x80C4CF8: do_foo (foo.c:1161)
==17110==    by 0x80AE325: xyzzy (bar.c:466)
==17110==    by 0x8097C46: io (bar.c:950)
==17110==    by 0x8098163: main (quux.c:1291)
```

Then you need to look at line 1161 in `foo.c`, which is within the function `do_foo()`.  That's where the memory was allocated (with `malloc()`), and only *you* can say where it should have been freed.

Comment: can u tell me what is the command to see where was the memory leak created please

Comment: @Nadav: The above example is just from the regular Valgrind output.  That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which compiler you are using, I suppose gcc?
Do you use `-g` to have debugging symbols included?

Comment: yea i use gcc and no i didnt use -g

Comment: In that case use -g and check, as debug symbols may not be available